# Startup problem in a fresh 12.10 installation

Tags: unity, boot, 12.10, compiz, login

I have downloaded 12.10 image recently, and burned it to disc to install on my laptop.
Everything worked fine until now, when I started it first time it got stuck on loading (Ubuntu title and dots below).

I tried restarting and it got through, but a new problem appeared. After typing my password and logging in, it just freezes there with background and mouse pointer only visible. I can start terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> but that's all.

Then after few minutes, error comes up saying that `application compiz has closed unexpectedly`. Whatever I click (relaunch or leave closed) it just stays frozen with background only.

Comment: What graphics driver are you using (e.g i915, radeon, nouveau, ...)?  Alternatively, what graphics card are you using?

Comment: intel corp. integrated graphics device 82852/855gm

Comment: Make sure you check the md5sum of the iso that you downloaded: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you do the following

- Put the livecd and test/see if all is working. This is to ensure everything with you system is well.
- Try login with Ubuntu Classic mode.
- Last possibility which i doubt is perhaps hard disk is corrupt.
- If you do a single user mode and paste the output of dmesg that will be great.

Comment: well, livecd gives me the same "compiz" error thingy

Comment: im new user could you explain 3 other things please,apart from har disk one.

where do i find classic mode?

Answer (score 1):

To get to classic mode, boot into ubuntu as normal, click your username top right of the screen, select logout.

Before you log back in, click the drop down at the right side of the username entry text field, you can select which environment you want to run.

Here you can select which "version" you boot, this refers to several things, but mostly its used for changing your desktop environment. 11.04 and onwards use Unity, but you can also try Gnome or KDE. Or you can bail back a few steps and take classic mode; if you're windows convert, you could think of it as safe mode+ .

All this info is out there, where I found it, but a point in the right direction can save hours...